# How can I set a blade expression using a PHP variable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

```
@section('title', {{exampleVariable}})
```

How can I achieve the above?

I've searched around for an answer but haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: Remove the `{{ }}`, and make sure to reference the variable correctly, like `$exampleVariable`

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
@section('title', $exampleVariable)
```

instead.

`{{` is just use to display variable, consider this as PHP `echo` method, and here you don't want to just echo variable value

Answer (score 1):

You could either do this:

```
@section('title', $exampleVariable)
```

**Or this:**

```
@section('title')
    {{ $exampleVariable }}
@endsection
```